# How to divide two nvarchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove GB from the data and Calculate the percentage Used.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp8') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp8
    select (REPLACE(sdCardUsed,'GB',''))used ,
    (REPLACE(sdCardFree,'GB','') ) free,

    (REPLACE(sdCardTotal,'GB','')) Total  
            into #temp8
            from DeviceInfo  order by _id desc

  Select ((REPLACE(sdCardUsed,'GB','')used) 
    *100/(REPLACE(sdCardTotal,'GB','')total) From #temp8)
        as Percentage
        From #temp8
        from DeviceInfo  
        Where total Is Not Null OR Total !=''
        order by _id desc
```

The expected result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  SdcardUsed        |  SdcardTotal | SdcardFree |  Expectec_Result        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   23.87GB          |    50.00GB   | 26.23GB    |    47.74%               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0.76GB           |    20.79GB   | 20.03GB    |    3.655%               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If this is an SQL question, please [edit] your question to add a tag for the specific flavour of SQL that you are using (looks like it might be [tag:sql-server]). We probably need the definition of `DeviceInfo`, some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: We can't run your code. So great, we have your attempt. We have your expected result. So what's *actually* happening? *sample data* and expected results helps us a lot. As does the *text* of any error messages Also, side note, you need to embrace things like subqueries, CTEs and/or apply. I can't see any reason why this needs to be broken into multiple separate queries using a temp table between them.

Answer (score 1):

If I take the first three columns of your expected result as the current contents of `DeviceInfo`, I can achieve your expected result (give or take some quibling over types) like so:

```
declare @DeviceInfo table (SdcardUsed varchar(15), SdcardTotal varchar(15), SdcardFree varchar(15))
insert into @DeviceInfo(SdcardUsed,SdcardTotal,SdcardFree) values
('23.87GB','50.00GB','26.23GB'),
('0.76GB' ,'20.79GB','20.03GB')

select
    di.*,(used * 100 / total) as UsedPercent
from
    @DeviceInfo di
        cross apply
    (values (CONVERT(decimal(15,5),REPLACE(SdCardUsed,'GB','')),
            CONVERT(decimal(15,5),REPLACE(SdCardTotal,'GB','')),
            CONVERT(decimal(15,5),REPLACE(SdCardFree,'GB','')))) t(used,total,free)
```

Note that I'm not using `free` but I've converted all 3 values from strings into decimals just to show the general technique. You can replace `di.*` with just `*` if you want to see all of the columns produced by the `apply`.

Result:

```
SdcardUsed      SdcardTotal     SdcardFree      UsedPercent
--------------- --------------- --------------- ----------------------
23.87GB         50.00GB         26.23GB         47.7400000000000000000
0.76GB          20.79GB         20.03GB         3.6556036556036556036
```

Comment: Still not converting.
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @UmeshGowda can you provide sample data

Comment: @UmeshGowda - then your input data doesn't look like the only data you *have* given us in the question or you're doing something additional around this query that you've not mentioned. The code in my answer is a complete script that executes without error. You need to help us to help you by e.g. putting good, clear sample data in your question.

Comment: SR _ID           USED  FREE TOTAL
1 6867 3.60 GB 5.12 GB 8.72 GB
2 6866 3.57 GB 5.16 GB 8.72 GB
3 6865 6.95GB 3.83GB 10.79GB
4 6864 3.57 GB 5.16 GB 8.72 GB

Comment: Beacause I might thinking the table has junk data which is unanle to convert to float type